# Replace string with regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I have the below situation

**Case 1:**

**Input :** `X(P)~AK,X(MV)~AK`

**Replace with:** `AP`

**Output:** `X(P)~AP,X(MV)~AP`

**Case 2:**

**Input:** `X(PH)~B$,X(PL)~B$,X(MV)~AP`

**Replace with**: `USD$`

**Output:** `X(PH)~USD$,X(PL)~USD$,X(MV)~USD$`

As can be make out that, always the `~<string>` will be replaced.

Is it possible to achieve the same through regular expression?

Note:~ Nothing will be known at compile time except the structure. A typical structure

goes like

```
X(<Variable Name>)~<Variable Name>
```

I am using C#3.0

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with C# - not C#3.0 nor any other. Your question has to do with .NET, which is where the regular expression support is. There is no regular expression support in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simple regex will do it:

`~(\w*[A-Z$])`

You can test it here:

http://regexhero.net/tester/

Select the tab Replace at RegexHero.

Enter `~(\w*[A-Z$])` as the Regular Expression.

Enter `~AP` as the Replacement string.

Enter `X(P)~AK,X(MV)~AK` as the Target String.

You'll get this as the output:

```
X(P)~AP,X(MV)~AP
```

In C# idiom, you'd have something like this:

```
class RegExReplace
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "X(P)~AK,X(MV)~AK";

        Console.WriteLine("text=[" + text + "]");

        string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"~(\w*[A-Z$])", "~AP");

        // Prints: [X(P)~AP,X(MV)~AP]
        Console.WriteLine("result=[" + result + "]");

        text = "X(PH)~B$,X(PL)~B$,X(MV)~AP";

        Console.WriteLine("text=[" + text + "]");

        result = Regex.Replace(text, @"~(\w*[A-Z$])", "~USD$");

        // Prints: [X(PH)~USD$,X(PL)~USD$,X(MV)~USD$]
        Console.WriteLine("result=[" + result + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program is great but fails in 

string text = "X(P)~%,X(MV)~%";
string selecteditem = "KP";
string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"~(\w*[A-Z$])", "~" + selecteditem);

Comment: Oh... add that percentile symbol % to the regex pattern. Like this: `~(\w*[A-Z$%])`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use string.Replace(string,string)?

Comment: At compile time it will not known to me  "AK" or "B$" .. So how can I apply that